# how to send media album from local storage on telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot that sends media from local storage and i got this error.

Also if there is a list with over 10 items on it and you try to send as a album does telegram automatically seperates them to different album to send it?

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified

```
import telebot
import glob
import os
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto, InputMediaVideo

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    id = message.chat.id
    path = "./vid/*.mp4"
    vid_media = []
    #i might remove this i think this is not needed 
    for files in glob.glob(path):
        print(files)

    for i in os.listdir("./vid/"):
        vid_media.append(InputMediaVideo(i))
    bot.send_message(id, "Sending videos...")
    for i in vid_media:
        with open(i, 'rb') as f:
            bot.send_media_group(id, vid_media)
bot.polling()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand why you `open()` file if you don't use it but you try to send `vid_media`> And you run it in loop `for i in vid_media` - so you try to send the same `vid_media` many times.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `listdir()` if you can use values from `glob()` - `for i in files:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't use directly path to local file.
You have to send content as bytes:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:   # open in `byte mode`
    data = fh.read()               # read bytes
    media = InputMediaVideo(data)  # put bytes

    vid_media.append(media)
```

---

Full working code:

```
import os
import glob
import telebot
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto, InputMediaVideo

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
#print('TOKEN:', TOKEN)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    path = "./vid/*.mp4"
    
    vid_media = []
    
    for filename in glob.glob(path):
        print('read:', filename)
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
            data = fh.read()
            media = InputMediaVideo(data)
            vid_media.append(media)
        
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Sending videos...")
    
    bot.send_media_group(chat_id, vid_media)
            
bot.polling()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Different modules may have different functionalities.

This code uses module `telebot` ([pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)) and it can't use local path
but it seems module `telegram` can use `pathlib.Path` with local path in its [InputMediaVideo](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.inputmediavideo.html).